# iMacros FOLDER Extraction on Mac OS

Tags: macos, imacros

Most examples iMacros scripts available on the internet are using Windows, but I'm confused and want to ask about the location of the full path of a result iMacros EXTRACT on Mac OS.

As an example of this URL `http://wiki.imacros.net/SAVEAS`
will extract the words "SAVEAS", which are located on the top page.

Here the script:

```
VERSION BUILD=8970419 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=http://wiki.imacros.net/SAVEAS
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:SAVEAS EXTRACT=TXT

SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=/users/myusername/something/etc/here<SP>my<SP>download/ FILE=sample.csv
```

Is that correct for the name of "FOLDER" location on Mac like this?

```
FOLDER=/users/myusername/something/etc/here<SP>my<SP>download/
```

I cannot try because I use Windows but I will apply my script in my client Macbook.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add double quotes around your folder path if it includes spaces.

```
FOLDER="/users/myusername/something/etc/here my download/"
```

[source](http://wiki.imacros.net/SAVEAS)